# a word that describes this phenomenon : 'the constituents are attributed a term, but the usage of the term does not imply the constituents'

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, linguistics

Here's a puzzle : I'm looking for a word (or a phrase) that describes the case where the components belong to a term, but the term does not essentially map back to the components.
I think it has something to do with a term whose underlying taxonomy is not-yet well defined, but the term is still used in everyday parlance.

Consider the entity 'alien' - unlike the word 'primate' or 'mammal', the use of the word 'alien' does not tell us anything about the creature itself - what it looks like, its limbs, abilities etc. It's a place-holder for an entity that needs to be defined each time in a specific context (of a book, film etc.). So, an 'alien' could have nine legs or twenty, or none at all, and yet be called an 'alien'.

EDIT: I think I found it - 'a catch-all term' seems to fit, a 'metaphoric dumping group' as Wikipedia defines it.

Comment: Hmm... I do have a possible candidate. Editing the post now.

Comment: You're not just talking about 'misnomer' are you? For example, a 'guinea pig' is readily recognised as being (the common name for) a familiar animal. However, this animal didn't originally come from Guinea, and is certainly not a pig. _If this is what you require, the question is a duplicate._

Comment: I wouldn't say that cloud computing relates to everything computer related. For instance my perfectly ordinary wristwatch, the simple control system for my central heating system and my desk calcuator have a certain amount of computing power and rely on computer technology but none of them is (thank goodness) connected to the internet and certainly make no use of Cloud Storage or Software As A Service applications.

Comment: That's exactly my point - using the word 'cloud computing' means one has to define what it isn't (like you did) rather than the word telling us what it is.

Comment: You seem to be heading towards either _hypernym_ (superset) or 'complement set' (colloquially, a dustbin). But your question remains unclear.

Comment: Have modified the question - hopefully clearer now!

Comment: @puzzle4you Please don't edit the question with an answer. Use the answer box and write your own answer! You might get rep points for it; and at the very least it shows other people that there has been an answer.